# How to make ionic music player in background?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an application for music on Ionic 3.
I need to know:
1) How to make the music play in background in android & ios?
2) How to make the player standard as in the picture

http://joxi.ru/L21oy7oHRDJe7r

[image]

Thanks, Vlad!

UPDATE:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/music-controls

Comment: I think you need to use: backgroundMode, refer this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-run-app-forever-in-background-like-whatsapp/12546/52